# How can I use Apache2 module in CGI mode?

Tags: perl, mod-perl

```
my $r = shift || Apache2::RequestUtil->request;
my $request = Apache2::Request->new($r, @_);
```

I know it was designed to be used with mod_perl,

but is there a workaround so that it can also be used in CGI mode?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing those two lines with ...

```
my $request = CGI->new();
```

The [Apache2::Request](https://metacpan.org/module/Apache2%3a%3aRequest) module wraps the mod_perl API in order to *"mimic the CGI.pm routines for parsing query parameters"*.  So any code that uses the raw $r won't work, but code using $request might.

But in answer to your bigger question, the answer is no there isn't an easy way to run code written for mod_perl under CGI instead.  When writing new code you should either use a framework or write to the PSGI API which can then me deployed using CGI, FastCGI or mod_perl without changing the code.